# Is it possible to snap to grid when doing an inset?

Tags: modeling, snapping

When insetting a new face is it possible to have it snap to grid?

I've got everything else (moving, rotation, scale) snapping to grid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you've inset the face[image] go to vertex select in the top left of the viewport and select the vertices on the face you inset and right click and click snap selection to grid.